# getElementById not returning the <div> element identified by the Id

Tags: javascript, html

When I load this page, it complains that the variable elem is null:

```html
<?php
/*
To test javascript to change the contents of a select element 
*/
$titleUnit = 'all';
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
const jobTitles = new Map();
const unit1titles = [];
const unit2titles = [];
jobTitles.set("P1", "Programmer");
unit1titles.push("P1");
jobTitles.set("A1", "Analyst");
unit1titles.push("A1");
jobTitles.set("C3", "Custodian");
unit2titles.push("C3");
jobTitles.set("L4", "Landscaper");
unit2titles.push("L4");
</script>

<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpading=5>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border=0>
                <tr>
                    <td valign='center' class="formLabel">Job Title</td>
                    <td class="formLabel"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<I>In Unit:</td>
                    <td valign='center' class="formLabel">
                        <input type='radio' name='titleUnit' value="U1" onclick="changeTUnit('U1')"<?php echo ($titleUnit=='U1' ? ' CHECKED' : ''); ?>> Unit 1
                        <input type='radio' name='titleUnit' value="U2" onclick="changeTUnit('U2')"<?php echo ($titleUnit=='U2' ? ' CHECKED' : ''); ?>> Unit 2
                        <input type='radio' name='titleUnit' value="all" onclick="changeTUnit('all')"<?php echo ($titleUnit=='all' ? ' CHECKED' : ''); ?>> All
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td class="formLabel">
            Job Code
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="formField">
            <select name="jt[]" MULTIPLE size=5 class="text9ptBlack">
                <option value="">Select Job Title</option>
                <div id='jTitles'></div>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="formField">
            <select name="jt[]" MULTIPLE size=5 class="text9ptBlack">
                <option value="">Select Title Code</option>
                <div id='tCodes'></div>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
function changeTUnit(newUnit) {
    var titleIH = "";
    var tCodes = [];
    switch (newUnit) {
        case 'all': tCodes = jobTitles.keys(); break;
        case "U1": tCodes = unit1titles.values(); break;
        case "U2": tCodes = unit2titles.values(); break;
    }
    for (let tC of tCodes) {
        titleIH += "<option value='" + tC + "'>" + jobTitles.get(tC) + "</option>\n";
        codeIH += "<option value='" + tC + "'>" + tC + "</option>\n";
    }       
alert("titleIH=\n" + titleIH); 
    var elem = document.getElementById('jTitles'); 
    elem.innerHtml = titleIH; 
}

document.addEventListener("load", changeTUnit('all'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot have a `div` inside a `select`. That is invalid HTML.

Comment: You might be thinking of `<optgroup>` if you want to group `<option>` elements.

Comment: You should probably change your load code to: `document.addEventListener("load", () => changeTUnit('all'));` - at the moment you're assigning the result of _calling_ the function rather than assigning a function to the listener which is what it expects.

Comment: Your code actually says that codeIH is null. It would be better if you posted the code that renders to the browser rather than the code that includes the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is with this line:

```
document.addEventListener("load", changeTUnit('all'));
```

You are actually invoking the `changeTUnit` function here, rather than referencing it. Instead, the line should be:

```
document.addEventListener("load", function() { changeTUnit('all') });
```

So that you can add a function reference that, in turn, calls the real function with its argument.

Also, your code relies on inline scripts, which are really a very old way of incorporating script into your HTML page. When this is done, some of your code can wind up executing as soon as the HTML parser encounters the script instead of waiting until the entire page loads. The simplest way to ensure that no code executes until the HTML is ready to be parsed is to just add your `<script>` just prior to the closing `body` tag. **No event handler is needed**.

Next, you are embedding `div` elements inside of `select` elements, which is not allowed.

You're also using deprecated HTML when you add your table and input attributes. CSS should be used for all styling. And, along those lines tables should not be used for layout as you are doing. Tables are for tabular data only.

You should clean up your HTML to make it valid before trying to diagnose your script issues.

Answer (score 0):

Using the HTML `<optgroup>` tag instead of the `<div>` tag resolved the problem. Thanks Heretic Monkey and Pointy.

Answer (score -2):

variable jobTitles is not defined:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWeJD.png)

Comment: It is defined, at the top: `const jobTitles = new Map();` Perhaps you didn't copy the code in its entirety? Impossible to say, since you provide a screenshot as evidence, not a [mre].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).